# How to verify SHA of Azure certificate used for ftps?

Tags: azure, certificate, ftps

I am trying to connect to my Azure web app through FileZilla, with FTP/S settings listed on my app inside the Azure portal (picture below), how can I ensure this certificate is actually from Microsoft?

[image]

In the next picture, how to ensure this is truly from Microsoft? I'm expecting a simple lookup table somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more an issue with Filezilla as it doesn't trust certs that your local machine trusts (see [feature request](https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/8175)).  Most Azure certs are signed by Baltimore Cyber Trust.  Here is a blog post announcing our change to [Baltimore Cyber Trust](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-root-certificate-migration/).

[image]